# How to make UpdateProgress render as span not div or make this div display:inline?

Tags: asp.net

How to make UpdateProgress render as span not div or make this div display:inline ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to add a class in CSS to apply the `display:inline`. This is made easier in .NET 4 as you can make the UpdatesProgess `ClientIDMode` static so you it wont get an autogenerated ID which allows you to know what the ID will be client side.

CSS

```
#UpdateProgress
{
    display:inline;
}
```

ASP.NET

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
```

EDIT: The fourth example on that page seems to offer a way to set what style is applied.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
var postBackElement;
function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
   if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack())
   {
      args.set_cancel(true);
   }
   postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();
   if (postBackElement.id == 'ButtonTrigger')
   {
     $get('UpdateProgress1').style.display = "inline";
   }
}
function EndRequest (sender, args) {
   if (postBackElement.id == 'ButtonTrigger')
   {
     $get('UpdateProgress1').style.display = "none";    
   }
}
function AbortPostBack() {
  if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
       prm.abortPostBack();
  }        
}
</script>
```

Comment: As mentioned in the answer setting the ClientIDMode="Static" ensures the client id is the same as what you specify. I understand your point about the inline style being applied bit of an oversight on my part. The only other suggestion I could offer unfortunately is to wrap the UpdateProgress in a div with the display:inline property :/ You could also try adding the updateProgress in the UpdatePanel content template